# Twitter API request rate limits

Tags: javascript, php, twitter, joomla

I am trying to show twitter user tweets and hashtag tweets by twitter Rest & Search Api. But they have certain request limits. I've read their help pages - [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1) & [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1/limits) but still I do not understand about their rate limits in version 1.1.

So here is what I want to be clear -

1. As I have many users and I will place tweet display in many pages, so how many Api requests are allowed for user tweets display by Rest api (as one request will be when a page viewed) per hour?
2. And likewise how many requests allowed hashtag tweets display by Search Api per hour simply?
3. Does the request limit set per username or username+count value? (here count value is setting number of tweets I want).
4. If I know well about 1 & 2 questions above, then how will be the cache setting will be appropriate? what duration of caching of twitter data will be right before sending another request so that request limit not exceeded?

Comment: Are you using the JTwitter package?

Comment: No i am using this - http://sonnyt.com/Tweetie/. Is jtwitter a plugin? link? And please answer my question 3 too.

Comment: is it jtwitter - http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php ? it seems a java language specific which i don't know.i know php.

Comment: No it is the joomla package for interacting with the Twitter api. It is in libraries/joomla/twitter.

Comment: Not getting where in jtwitter package there are files for joomla. but i saw codes in joomla 3.3, say under joomla site's libraries/joomla/twitter/statuses.php and it's not using cache it just checks rate limit first by another api call. But i want to use cache for best ways of display. also if anyone know about my question #3.